# Customizing The JavaFX DatePicker Control

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

When clicking the button to go to the next month, when the month name is a different length from the previous, the button's location sometimes shifts slightly to the right or left to compensate for the longer or shorter month name.  This gets annoying to users trying to click multiple times to get to a month in the future--the button should remain in the same location to allow for this fast traversal.

Is it possible to alter the format of the month name at the top of a JavaFX DatePicker so it uses a 3 letter month name like JUL/FEB/MAR, make the label's width stay consistent, or otherwise keep the location of the button consistent?

Comment: This doesn't happen for me: the buttons stay in the same place no matter what the name of the month is. What JDK version are you using?

Comment: Using JDK 1.8.0_77, and that's interesting.

Comment: I tested on both 1.8.0_71 and 1.8.0_92 (just versions I happened to have on my machine) and both worked without the button moving.

Comment: I'll have to try it on another PC I guess..  are you using FXML? Windows?   
Nothing unusual being set here... omitting prefWidth doesn't stop it: 
<DatePicker prefWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />  Maybe, could it be inheriting some property messing it up?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - I'm setting -fx-font-size to 14 inside .root for the css file to make the font larger globally.

Overriding just that component's font back fixes it, but it'd still be nice to have a better workaround than this...

```
.date-picker {
-fx-font-size: 10;
}
```

Another slightly better solution which lets you maintain the larger font for the control:

```
.spinner-label {
-fx-min-width: 100;
}
```

(Adjust minimum width as needed depending on how large your font size is.)